# Oracle command to create a table from another schema, including triggers?

Tags: oracle

Using this command, I am able to create a table from another schema, but it does not include triggers. Is it possible to create a table from another schema, including triggers?

`create table B.tablename unrecoverable as select * from A.tablename where 1 = 0;`

Comment: If you can use products like SQL Developer, you have several options that allows you to extract the DDL for a table.

Comment: @Sam it would be useful to me to be able to script the creation of the tables

Comment: No need to create a script, you can literally pull the DDL from SQL Developer, change the name of the object where applicable, and then run the DDL just like you would any other script. You can download SQL Developer for free at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html

Answer (score 1):

First option is to run **CREATE script** for those objects, if you have a code repository. I suppose you don't.

If you use any **GUI** tool, things are getting simpler as they contain the SCRIPT tab that enables you to copy code from source and paste it into target user.

If you're on **SQLPlus**, it means that you should, actually, *know* what you're supposed to do. Here's a short demo.

```
SQL> connect hr/hr@xe
Connected.
SQL> create table detail (id number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_det
  2  before insert on detail
  3  for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.id := 1000;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL>

SQL> -- you'll have to grant privileges on table to another user
SQL> grant all on detail to scott;

Grant succeeded.
```

Connect as SCOTT and check what we've got:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger@xe
Connected.
SQL> -- now, query ALL_SOURCE and you'll get trigger code
SQL> set pagesize 0
SQL> col text format a50
SQL> select text from all_source where name = 'TRG_DET' order by line;
trigger trg_det
before insert on detail
for each row
begin
  :new.id := 1000;
end;

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Yet another option is to **export & import** table, which will get the trigger as well (I've removed parts that aren't relevant, as Oracle database version):

```
C:\>exp hr/hr@xe tables=detail file=detail.dmp
About to export specified tables via Conventional Path ...
. . exporting table                         DETAIL          0 rows exported
Export terminated successfully without warnings.

C:\>imp scott/tiger@xe file=detail.dmp full=y
. importing HR's objects into SCOTT
. importing HR's objects into SCOTT
. . importing table                       "DETAIL"          0 rows imported
Import terminated successfully without warnings.

C:\>
```

Check what's imported (should be both table and trigger):

```
SQL> desc detail
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ---------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER

SQL> select * From detail;

no rows selected

SQL> insert into detail (id) values (-1);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From detail;

        ID
----------
      1000

SQL>
```

Cool; even the trigger works.

There might be some other options, but these 4 should be enough to get you started.